# Yeoman Webapp SASS won't load

Tags: css, sass, http-status-code-404

when I create a webapp via 'yo webapp' I get an 404 Error

```
GET http://localhost:9000/styles/main.css 404 (Not Found)
```

I've deleted compass but that can't be the problem right?

Comment: So...is the file there? What version of Yeoman?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.tmp folder was outside of the app folder.

Answer (score 2):

The same issue happened for me when I was using alpha version of sass. Version 3.2.12 works fine and doesn't give any 404 errors.